# Adding something programmatically to an iOS view

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to get some AdWhirl ads to work with my app, but I am having a bit of trouble positioning them.  The ads work just fine with the following code in my viewDidLoad method:

```
AdWhirlView *adWhirlView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:adWhirlView];
```

The problem is that it displays the add across the top of the view.  I am assuming this is because the default drawing area is from 0,0.  I don't know how to change the self.view line to draw it towards the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this....

```
AdWhirlView *adWhirlView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
adWhirlView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, adWhirlView.frame.size.width, adWhirlView.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:adWhirlView];
```

It should show the new view further below (100 points) -  adapt that 100.0f according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
view.frame = CGMakeRect(x,y,w,h);
```